# Windows Vista Local Area Connection Not Working

Tags: windows, windows-vista, lan

So I have a Windows Vista and the local area connection worked fine until I moved the PC to a different room. After I moved it I tried using local area connection and it doesn't work so I run a diagnostics and the computer says that a `Cable is unplugged from the network adapter.`. I checked that the cable was connected properly and it still doesn't work. I am connected to internet and it works fine but the local area connection doesn't. Please help and thank you.